# Consider "Hinduism.SE" for the review towards the graduation process

Tags: feature-request, community, beta

We, the Hinduism StackExchange community have been receiving 10+ QPD (Questions Per Day) for more than about 3 months. According to the [Graduation, site closure, and a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/260388),

> When a site starts to consistently receive 10 questions/day, we’ll consider it for graduation.

After the perseverance of 3.5 years, the community has achieved fine statistics on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53689/hinduism)! Apart from QPD, we have good number of avid users and excellent (8-10k) visits per day.

Hence, We are requesting the team to consider this community for the **graduation review**.

We are grateful to StackExchange for providing a very reliable platform!

Comment: Will someone notice this post outside of HSE community?

Comment: @Rajas. sure, SE staff visits all meta sites, maybe not any moment, but surely once a day or two. They also got feeds, etc. Also, moderators can contact SE staff directly in a dedicated chat room called "Teachers Lounge"

Comment: One thing to note here Islam.se have [betetr stats](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14922/islam) then us and still didn't got graduated yet. Maybe we need to work on out answered percentage to improve.

Comment: @AnkitSharma They have not achieved the QPD yet which is more important factor to be considered. And btw, answering all the questions is bit difficult for our community.

Comment: @Pandya I have seen many sites getting graduation before hitting 10 QPD, I am sure it's not the only factor needed for graduation .

Comment: @AnkitSharma Well, it's not the only factor, however it's the first factor to consider according to the meta post I've cited.

Comment: @Pandya that meta is stale and SE seems to be little vague about it. But yeah that 5 point stats is required but not sure on which level. Maybe ping some CM to get tehre input.

Comment: The answer percentage is low, looks like we got so much work to do :)

Comment: @AnkitSharma Then they should either change/update the criteria or follow it.