# Who all visit the Hinduism.SE & how does it really influence others?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, site-evaluation

As per [this post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1125/1049), the total visits to Hinduism.SE is 8-10k per day.
This number could be quite high compared to the total registered users. Also, active users are much less and the daily contributing users are even quite less.

That means, majority of the views could be from the general populace.

1. Is there a way to know from where all these views are coming?
2. **Little subjective query**: What probability do you see that, moving forward, this SE can influence overall Hindu community and could be noticed in media outlets or spiritual platforms? So far I haven't heard any word of mouth.

The 2nd Qn is because, due to "source back-up" rule, the answers in this website provides more authenticity than other blogs, websites and Quora.

Comment: I don't think our site is influencing anyone. The buzz about site is very less. About authenticity, many users are just copying from other websites instead of writing own answers.In some cases, from Quora too. So, we are not that great when it comes to authenticity. Besides these, there are wrong answers too. I'm not sure we can answer your 2nd question. How will we know what others think and its influence?

Comment: Views and visits are different. You can get the views this month at Google analytics page in Moderator Tools. They are ~8.3k per day. This is not about post quality. It is to be used for discussion about Low quality questions and answers.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma We need some improvement but still due to "source back-up" rule we are better than many sites, blogs of this domain when it comes to authenticity...

Comment: We have to say that to satisfy ourselves. We copy paste from those websites and still say better than those. I will also join the group then.

Comment: "how does it really influence others?"..I saw Hinduism.SE in citations/references section in few wikis...